# Multicasting through all network interfaces by setting IP_MULTICAST_IF?

Tags: c, linux, sockets, networking

I need to multicast a packet through all the interfaces that have multicast capabilities in my machine. By setting IP_MULTICAST_IF with setsockopt() I can choose through which interface I'd like to multicast my packets. Unfortunately I can only choose one (can't I?). A possible solution would be to set IP_MULTICAST_IF, multicast the packet through that interface reset IP_MULTICAST_IF, send another packet and so on. Unfortunately, socket options cannot be modified while the socket is connected... what could be a possible solution to my problem?

Comment: Why are you `connect`ing the socket?

Comment: Your possible solution (changing the IP_MULTICAST_IF setting just before sending each packet) works fine for me.  Steve-o is right though, if you are calling connect() on a multicast socket that is a mistake, since it means the socket will discard incoming packets coming from any source other than the one the socket is connect()'d to... which is not usually what you want in a multicast situation.  Use sendto() and recvfrom() instead.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution is to have a socket per interface, but I would question your network setup where you "need to multicast a packet through all the interfaces" - that usually is a sign of bad design.

Comment: If the goal of the program is to discover what multicast listeners are out there, how would you do it without sending a multicast packet on every connected interface?

Comment: Yeah, I guess this might make sense for service discovery.

Comment: Exactly. I contributed a patch to Jini years ago that did exactly this. In multi homed hosts it is essential.

Comment: EJP: could you elaborate a little bit on how you solved your problem?

Comment: +1. Enumerate your interfaces (eg using an open-source getifaddrs wrapper to add support for each OS), then have a socket per interface. That's what I do for my UPnP library.